# Extending types in third-party library for serialization

Tags: f#

I need a function to convert types from a third-party library to `IDictionary`s so they can be easily serialized (to JSON). There are dependencies between the types so the dictionaries are sometimes nested.

Right now I have something hideous like this:

```
//Example type
type A(name) = 
  member __.Name  = name

//Example type
type B(name, alist) =
  member __.Name = name
  member __.AList : A list = alist

let rec ToSerializable x =
  match box x with
  | :? A as a -> dict ["Name", box a.Name]
  | :? B as b -> dict ["Name", box b.Name; "AList", box (List.map ToSerializable b.AList)]
  | _ -> failwith "wrong type"
```

This would convert everything to a primitive type, an `IEnumerable` of such a type, or a dictionary.

This function will keep growing as types are added (ugh). It's not type-safe (requiring the catch-all pattern). Figuring out which types are supported requires perusing the monolithic pattern match.

I'd love to be able to do this:

```
type ThirdPartyType with
  member x.ToSerializable() = ...

let inline toSerializable x =
  (^T : (member ToSerializable : unit -> IDictionary<string,obj>) x)

let x = ThirdPartyType() |> toSerializable //type extensions don't satisfy static member constraints
```

So, I'm looking for creativity here. Is there a better way to write this that addresses my complaints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible solution that addresses the type-safety question, though not necessarily your extensibility question:

```
// these types can appear in any assemblies
type A = { Name : string }
type B = { Name : string; AList : A list }
type C(name:string) =
    member x.Name = name
    static member Serialize(c:C) = dict ["Name", box c.Name]
```

```
// all of the following code goes in one place
open System.Collections.Generic

type SerializationFunctions = class end

let inline serializationHelper< ^s, ^t when (^s or ^t) : (static member Serialize : ^t -> IDictionary<string,obj>)> t = 
    ((^s or ^t) : (static member Serialize : ^t -> IDictionary<string,obj>) t)
let inline serialize t = serializationHelper<SerializationFunctions,_> t

// overloads for each type that doesn't define its own Serialize method
type SerializationFunctions with
    static member Serialize (a:A) = dict ["Name", box a.Name]
    static member Serialize (b:B) = dict ["Name", box b.Name; "AList", box (List.map serialize b.AList)]

let d1 = serialize { A.Name = "a" }
let d2 = serialize { B.Name = "b"; AList = [{ A.Name = "a" }]}
let d3 = serialize (C "test")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do `x.Items |> Array.map (unbox >> serialize) |> box`. It seems there's no way to cast to `^t` where `^t requires member ToSerializable`.

Comment: @Daniel - right, because `^t` must be statically known, so it doesn't make sense to do that at runtime.  You could potentially use reflection instead.

Answer (score 2):

as quick-n-obvious idea: use overloads

```
//Example type
type A(name) = 
  member __.Name  = name

//Example type
type B(name, alist) =
  member __.Name = name
  member __.AList : A list = alist

type Converter =
    static member ToSerializable(a : A) = dict ["Name", box a.Name]
    static member ToSerializable(b : B) = dict ["Name", box b.Name; "AList", box (b.AList |> List.map Converter.ToSerializable)]
```

Comment: It's funny, this likely would have been obvious to me several years ago. My venture into functional programming apparently has a corresponding departure from OO.