# Dynamic dispatch for third-party type

Tags: f#, dynamic-dispatch

This is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10020242/162396) about extending third-party types in a type-safe way. There were some good answers but they rely on the concrete type being known at compile time. I can't depend on this. Sometimes the type is boxed. Is there a way to extend third-party types to simulate dynamic dispatch?

I would use an interface for my own library. For example:

```
type ICanSerialize =
  abstract ToSerializable : unit -> IDictionary<string,obj>

type B(items: obj[]) =
  interface ICanSerialize with
    member __.ToSerializable() = 
      dict ["Items", items |> Array.map (fun x -> 
        (x :?> ICanSerialize).ToSerializable()) |> box]
```

As a side note, it would be nice if we could do:

```
let inline toSerializable x =
  (^T : (member ToSerializable : unit -> IDictionary<string,obj>) x)

let x = obj()
let d = toSerializable (unbox x)
```

But obviously it's impossible to combine runtime casts and inlining.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to have some cast-like operation that takes a dynamically loaded object of unknown type (`System.Object`) and casts that to some structural type and, preferrably guarantees that the object supports all operations that are specified by this type.

I don't think there is a standard machinery for that, but it could be implemented using `System.Reflection.` `Emit`. I implemented something similar for [interoperability between C# and PHP some time ago](http://tomasp.net/blog/ducktyping-in-phalaner.aspx).

The idea is to write a function that dynamically generates a class implementing the interface and all members of the interface are simply delegated to members of the wrapped object. While wrapping the object, you can check that all members exist and have the right signatures (but the object does not actually have to implement the same interface).

This is a bit too much code for a code sample, but I hope the general idea will be useful too (search [Phalanger source code](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/) for `NewObject` method if you want to see how it is done there).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this. Although, `Reflection.Emit` is a bit overkill for the problem I'm trying to solve.